# Angular values are not reflecting in view

Tags: angular

Angular values are not reflecting in view

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-6 cardexpiry-block" [ngClass]="{'cardexpiry-block-remove':!!hasCardExpiryDate}"><!-- -->
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-left"><label for="CardExpiry">Card Expiry</label></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 text-left d-inline-flex"> <input name="hasCardExpiry" type="radio" (click)="hasCardExpiry(true)">
        Yes </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 text-left d-inline-flex"> <input name="hasCardExpiry" type="radio" (click)="hasCardExpiry(false)"
            checked> No</div>
    <my-date-picker *ngIf="!!hasCardExpiryDate" name="CardExpiry" [options]="myDatePickerOptions"
        formControlName="expiryDate"></my-date-picker>
</div>
```

**TS Code:**

```
hasCardExpiryDate : boolean = false;

hasCardExpiry(falg){
    this.hasCardExpiryDate = falg;
}
```

When I toggle between Yes and No, the values if "hasCardExpiryDate" is not changing 
when i check-in HTML using  `{{ hasCardExpiryDate | json }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an Error.

these changes are working fine, the problem I figured out it. one of the form control fields is not binding the value. problem is I can't see any issue in my console. I debug in code. now all everything is working fine.

Thanks for your time guys.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `ngModel` and `value`

```
<input name="hasCardExpiry" type="radio" [value]="true" [(ngModel)]="hasCardExpiryDate" (click)="hasCardExpiry(true)"> Yes 



<input name="hasCardExpiry" type="radio" [value]="false" [(ngModel)]="hasCardExpiryDate" (click)="hasCardExpiry(true)" checked> No
```

Comment: See, I just want to show/ hide the date picker, I don't want to save the values of radio buttons. if that is the case I might use formControlName for the radio button right instead if ngModel.

Comment: yaa.. you can use formControlname too. or try this : `[checked]="hasCardExpiryDate"`

Comment: Still, changes are not reflecting in Edit mode. Works fine in Add Mode.

Comment: Problem is the latest value is not binding to `"hasCardExpiryDate"` in Edit Mode.

Comment: In edit mode, from where are u getting the rest of the data?

Answer (score 0):

Use *ngIf = hasCardExpiryDate  on specified div. It will show and hide the div for the corresponding value .

or 
use *ngShow = !hasCardExpiryDate to show hide the div.